# User-defined type not defined error

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am very new to VBA Excel Programming.  I keep getting a "User-defined type not defined" error.  I searched everywhere and cannot find the answer to my specific problem. A lot of the solutions required adding references, which doesn't seem to apply to my situation.  The calculation returns properly but the error message drives me crazy! Also the macro call at the end is not happening.

```
    Function MinutesOver(duration, start_time, end_time)

      If Not (duration = "") Then
        If ((duration * 60) > 600) Or (((duration * 60) + (start_time * 24 * 60)) >    (TimeValue("17:00:00") * 24 * 60)) Then
          MinutesOver = (duration * 60) - ((end_time - start_time) * 24 * 60)
        Else
          MinutesOver = ""
        End If
      Else
        MinutesOver = ""
      End If

      Call AddRowDeleteConstants

    End Function
```

I even tried to make a simpler version but I still get the same error.

```
    Function MinutesOver(duration As Integer)
      MinutesOver = duration
     'Call AddRowDeleteConstants
    End Function
```

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    Sub AddRowDeleteConstants() 
      'On Error GoTo NoConstants 
      With ActiveCell.EntireRow
        .Copy 
        .Insert Shift:=xlDown 
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents 
      End With 
    Exit Sub 

     'NoConstants: 
     'MsgBox "There were no constants to delete"
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is AddRowDeleteConstants ? What line is the error on? (if you cant tell, press f9 on the Function MinutesOver(.. line to set a break point, run the call, press F8 when breaking to run the next line)

Comment: I stepped all the way through it with F8 and the error doesn't happen until it is finished (after it gets to End Function line).  The AddRowDeleteConstants looks like this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I to ran your function with no errors, but...

A user defined function cannot modify other cells.  In the call to `AddRowDeleteConstants`, whether or not it errors,  the commands `Copy`, `Insert` and `PasteSpecial` do nothing because they are in effect called from the user defined function.

Comment: Thanks, for this information.  I could have lived with the error, but since modifying other cells from a user-defined function is not possible I will have to come up with a different plan.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not getting any errors with your code, but maybe you need to give your function a type?

```
Function MinutesOver(duration As Integer) as Integer
```

just a guess...

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, still getting the same error. :(

Comment: This "guess" is completely irrelevant and not useful at all... -1